# Is it possible to change the 'hardware version' in VMWare player?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-player, disk-image

I am using the latest version of VMWare Player, and I need to create an image for a server.  Is it possible to downgrade the hardware version to version 7 (equivalent to VMWare Player 3.xx), rather than hardware version 9 which is available on VMWare Player 5.xx

Comment: I am pretty sure there is a command line tool that will acomplish this.

Comment: And any ideas how?

Comment: I would have to do a Google search to give you the exact command.